# Как включить CORS или OPTIONS метод в AWS Lambda Function Handler без API Gateway в коде?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

У меня есть метод lambda на JAVA. Когда я посылаю запрос методом `OPTIONS`, я поучаю `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`. Метод `GET` работает нормально.

Как я могу включить `OPTIONS` или `CORS` в коде, не используя API Gateway?